# npm ERR! Installing firebase to angular

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: userinterface@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@10.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"^10.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"15.2.9" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@15.2.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!   @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^15.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/fire@7.6.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/fire
npm ERR!     @angular/fire@"^7.6.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Zhadi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-30T11_27_46_703Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Zhadi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-30T11_27_46_703Z-debug-0.log`
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "userinterface",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.23.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.802.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

How can i resolve this error

Comment: what is our angular version ?

Comment: Use `ng update` command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your angular version using the command `ng v`
and then choose the right version of angularfire from the table bellow:

| Angular | Firebase | AngularFire |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 9 | ^7.6 |
| 15 | 9 | ^7.5 |
| 14 | 9 | ^7.4 |
| 13 | 9 | ^7.2 |
| 12 | 9 | ^7.0 |
| 12 | 7,8 | ^6.1.5 |
| 11 | 7,8 | ^6.1 |
| 10 | 8 | ^6.0.4 |
| 10 | 7 | ^6.0.3 |
| 9 | 8 | ^6.0.4 |
| 9 | 7 | ^6.0 |

then use the command `npm i @angular/fire@VERSION` and in VERSION put the right version.

**example**

`npm install @angular/fire@6.1`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire/v/7.6.1?activeTab=readme